# How to make a component function in typescript

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to make a component function.

Complier says.
JSX element type 'MyComponent' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.

```
enter code here
```

```
class MyComponent {
    render() { return <div>a</div>};
}

export class ExamPage extends Component<Props, {}> {
render(){
    return (  <MyComponent />
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a functional component, it could look something like this:

```
const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      a
    </div>
  );
};
```

`MyComponentProps` is an interface like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

Answer (score 0):

Every `class component` must extend `Component` simply add `extends Component` to `MyComponent`

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>a</div>;
  }
}
```